# How to deploy a contract by manually signing it?

Tags: blockchain, web3-providers

what all options are there to deploy a contract by manually signing instead of using library built in methods.

Comment: At some point you'll a library to create a cryptographic signature. A deployment transaction it like a regular transaction the only difference is that *to* field should be empty, and the *data* fields contains the deployment bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://medium.com/@gus_tavo_guim/deploying-a-smart-contract-the-hard-way-8aae778d4f2a)

It is already 5 years old and may be not compatible with current state of ethereum, but it is good in explaining how deploy it with minimum of libraries.

To continue work on ethereum project I would suggest Remix IDE and hardhat https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/test-contracts